# Extracting neighbourhood names from a shapefile for a set of coordinates

Tags: r, geolocation, gis, shapefile

I have a data frame of geo-coordinate pairs (latitudes, longitudes)

| geo_loc.Latitude | geo_loc.Longitude |
| --- | --- |
| 11.8 | 13.2 |
| 11.8 | 13.2 |
| 11.8 | 13.2 |
| 11.8 | 13.2 |
| 11.8 | 13.2 |
| 11.8 | 13.2 |

And I have a shapefile that contains neighbourhoods

How can I pull the neighbourhoods from the shapefile for each pair of geo-coordinates?

Comment: If you have a common unique identify for each site in the dataframe and the shapefile, you can use geo_join {tigris} or merge {sp}

Comment: I think `dfr %over% shapefile` will do what you want.

Comment: Or, if you are using the newer `sf` package, you could use `st_join`